# How would you tackle computing a correlation of two columns within a 1-million column CSV?

Tags: python, pandas, csv, bigdata, pearson-correlation

Scenario:

- I have a CSV with the first column "Age", and a million
  other columns across. I want to find the columns that are most
  correlated with Age.
- Row count is low, let's say under 1000 rows.
- This is part of a larger solution written in Python, but this doesn't have to be python.
- Like most things, I want to balance code readibility with performance
- In the example below I look at only one column for simplicity.  Real solution will probably use multiprocessing of all cols.

I have code below that will work, but it is understandably slow with a CSV stored as a Pandas dataframe that is very (very!) wide.

If it was you, what would you do?

**cmdline: `python mycode.py myfile.csv columnname-to-measure`**

```
import pandas as pd
from scipy import stats   
import os,sys

if __name__=="__main__":
    
    _DATAFILE = sys.argv[1]

    ##Sample tiny datafile
    
    #Age,m1,m2,m3
    #35,0.00234,0.1,1
    #30,0.0034,0.2,2
    #40,0.0013,0.3,4

    _MEASURE=sys.argv[2]

    print("Parsing file %s" %(_DATAFILE))
    
    df = pd.read_csv(_DATAFILE)
    print(f"Corellating {_MEASURE} with Age")
    all =df[['Age',_MEASURE]].copy()
    allna=all[all[_MEASURE].notna()]
    pearson_coef, p_value = stats.pearsonr( allna['Age'].values,allna[_MEASURE].values)
    print(pearson_coef,p_value)
```

Answer (score 0):

1. It is better to read all columns at once and compute all correlations so you can avoid read the file multiple times. Alternatively, use columnar storage such as parquet to store your file, so you can only read columns that you want. Check out pandas.read_parquet and df.to_parquet.
2. use pandas built-in correlation method tends to be faster (underlying numpy implementation ). https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.corr.html
3. I don't see multiprocessing will give too much speed up because your bottleneck is csv IO time, not the correlation computing time. Either read the file in one go or use parquet or some sort.

Comment: Thanks very much for this Leo, I haven't tried parquet, but I will.

Answer (score 0):

Is using [`pandas.DataFrame.corr`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.corr.html) too slow for your use case? It will compute a bunch of unnecessary correlations, but I'd start there. If it is too slow, then you could try [`numpy.corrcoef`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.corrcoef.html). I compared these two with your example data:

```py
data = [[35,0.00234,0.1,1],
        [30,0.0034,0.2,2],
        [40,0.0013,0.3,4]]

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['Age', 'm1', 'm2', 'm3'])
np_data = df.to_numpy()
```

Timing them with the `%timeit` magic function in a Jupyter Lab environment:

```py
%timeit df.corr()
```

yields `216 µs ± 24.3 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)`. Trying the `numpy` route:

```
%timeit np.corrcoef(np_data, rowvar=False)
```

yields `88 µs ± 1.4 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)`. So `np.corrcoef` is a bit faster.

For comparison with `scipy.stats.pearsonr`, I wrapped a column-iteration strategy in a function for timing it:

```py
def orig(df):
    for col in df.columns:
        pearson_coef, p_value = stats.pearsonr(df['Age'], df[col])
```

If we time this:

```py
%timeit orig(df)
```

We get `450 µs ± 46.4 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)`, so both `pandas.DataFrame.corr` and `numpy.corrcoef` are faster, despite having to compute unnecessary correlations.

Comment: hmm.  Using  pandas.DataFrame.corr with that many correlations required 5.2 TiB of memory.  `MemoryError: Unable to allocate 5.22 TiB for an array with shape (847081, 847081) and data type float64`

Comment: Ah, darn. I wonder if a blended approach could work, where chunks of some (configurable, depending on memory) number of columns are taken, and the correlations with age computed with `pandas.DataFrame.corr` or `numpy.corrcoef` on each chunk.